# how to find probability that either a or b occurs

Tags: probability

can you check my answers for this question?
for c i got 0.3 * 0.5 = 0.15
for b i multiplied the outcome of a by b compliment, but b compliment is still .5, so is the answer the same as c?
and for a i know it means a union b but i dont know how to calculate it?

Suppose that A and B are mutually exclusive events for which

P(A) = 0.3 and P(B) = 0.5. What is the probability that
(a) either A or B occurs?
(b) A occurs but B does not?
(c) both A and B occur?

Comment: Do you know what "mutually exclusive" means?

Comment: yes, that means the outcomes don't overlap between p(a) and p(b), or in other words they have distinct outcomes from eachother

Comment: Yes - in other words, that A and B cannot both occur. Does this help you with parts b) and c) at least?

Comment: does c = 0.8 and b = 0.3? i just realized a and b represents probability and not number of outcomes because they are subsets of #S which equals 1, right

Comment: The answer to part c) isn't 0.8, but your answer to b) is correct. Remember, mutually exclusive means that A and B **cannot both occur**

Comment: arent a and b subsets of #S where all the outcomes a and b contain are distinct (mutually exclusive) meaning that if both of these subsets occur you add 0.3 and 0.5 because they quetion is asking what is the probability of both occur,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A and B are mutually exclusive then $P(A\cap B) = 0$.

For a), take into account that $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$. For b), note that the probability of $B$ not ocurring is $P(B^c)$, and c) should be clear.

Edit:

$A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A)$, where the sets are disjoint. It is a principle that the probability of the union of disjoint sets is the sum of the probabilities of each set of the union. In particular
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A\setminus B)+ P(A\cap B) +P(B\setminus A).$$

Also $A\setminus B = A \setminus (A\cap B)$. Note that $[A \setminus (A\cap B)]\cup [A\cap B] = A.$ Since the sets in brackets are disjoint: $P(A\setminus B) + P(A\cap B) = P(A)$. Symmetrically $P(B) = P(B\setminus A) + P(A\cap B)$. It then follows that $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: i understand your explanation for a and b so is the question asking for a numerical answer or is what you wrote valid? because i am having trouble translating that into a numerical value?

Comment: when you wrote P(A intersection B) for part a, how can that make sense if a and b are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @idknuttin recall that if $A$ and $B$ have empty intersection, then $A\cap B = \emptyset$, and $P(\emptyset) = 0$. I'm giving you the answer in terms of the probability of events, those probabilities are given to you numerically, you just replace them. but, are you understanding the equations I wrote?

Comment: i understand your equation and what unon and intersections are but we both agree that A∩B=0 so how can either a or b occuring equal  P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B) when P(A∩B)=0 and P(A)+P(B) equals .8 which doesnt make sense because thats the probability of both a and b occuring

Comment: @idknuttin the probability of both $A$ **and** $B$ occurring is the probability of $A\cap B$, do you understand why? Let's give $A$ and $B$ some names (not related with your specific problem). You toss a coin, $A$ is when you get heads, $B$ tails. Is the probability of getting heads **and** tails at the same time $P(A)+P(B)$? NO! you will never get heads and tails at the same time, you can only get one.

Comment: thank you, so a) 0.8, b) 0.3 and c) 0, i understand it now